# What is the Flutter Console?

Tags: flutter

As I am following the ['Get Started' documentation on Flutter for Windows](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows), out of nowhere, there is a reference to the *'Flutter Console'*:

> You are now ready to run Flutter commands in the Flutter Console!

Later the documentation request you to ...

> In the Flutter Console, run the following command to see if there are
>   any dependencies you need to install to complete the setup:
>
> > `$ flutter doctor`

**What is this magical *'Flutter Console'*?**

Earlier, they describe Flutter depends on PowerShell 5.0; is PowerShell the Flutter Console?

The documentation lists an optional step to add the flutter 'bin' folder to PATH environment variables *"[i]f you wish to run Flutter commands in the regular Windows command prompt"*. This does not seem optional to me, as running `flutter doctor` is not recognized in PowerShell (which for the time being I will assume is the Flutter Console). I did run `flutter.bat`, but this window closed after some time. Perhaps this was supposed to be the Flutter Console?

Did I miss something in the setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`flutter_console.bat`** is located in the root of your Flutter folder and not in the sub-folder called `bin`, e.g. `..\flutter\flutter_console.bat` and `..\flutter\bin\flutter.bat` are the files you have mistaken. You checked the `bin` folder. Here is a screenshot of the *Flutter Console*.

[image: screenshot]

The image should explain what it does, it allows you to access `flutter` commands, which are calling the `flutter.bat`. That is the reason why you cannot interact with the latter when *double-clicking* it because you are not sending any parameters and it is not configured as a console window, i.e. it does not pause and wait for more input.

*The **Flutter Console** just lets you execute commands in the right directory if you have not added it to **PATH** because if you have `..\flutter\bin\` in **PATH** you can access the `flutter` commands from anywhere*.

Comment: See - can use Flutter for almost a year and not know it has it's own Console too .. :-)

Comment: I think that they only added it as a *workaround solution*. You could have it on an USB drive or not have permission to edit the **path**, which would make it inconvenient to access `flutter` commands from the console. In addition the *IDE plugins* for Flutter replace the need of command prompt usage as well. I have neither *used* it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, as well as explaining what the `flutter_console.bat` specifically does. :)

Comment: Makes sense. Trying to figure out going forward too if it makes sense to "check in" the version of Flutter you used when building a particular solution for production - then a bug/hot-fix wouldn't have to recreate the Flutter version and Dart version level on a development machine that may have moved forward (and possibly broken compatibility).  So a "portable" solution is important to have. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Note to **whoever maintains the Flutter documentation**: although obviously I was at fault by not reading the documentation thoroughly (as we hasty developers sometimes do), the documentation could be slightly improved by announcing in step 3 what exactly happens, i.e., _"Open the Flutter Console by double-clicking the .bat file."_ It does sound stupid now I did not notice, but I just read '.bat' and intuitively reached for the bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

The *Flutter Console* is a specific terminal window shipped with the [Flutter installation bundle for windows](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/).

It is installed when the bundle .zip is extracted.

As the installation page says, you can locate the file *flutter_console.bat* inside the `flutter` directory and you can start it by double-clicking.

Answer (score 1):

the flutter console is just a batch file for this commands

```
REM "%~dp0" is the directory of this file including trailing backslash
```

"%~dp0" expands to current directory path of the running batch file.

```
SET PATH=%~dp0bin;%PATH%

CALL cmd /K "@echo off & cd %USERPROFILE% & echo on"
```

**but the flutter console mentioned in the [doc](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/) is not what you are running . you can find the flutter console in the flutter main folder**
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is added as a path workaround, but I do not think that it is important to mention this. The OP rather had trouble finding the console than looking at the file's *code*.

Comment: yes you are right , i was trying to give the answer for the "what" part from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Flutter Console right inside the SDK folder called `flutter.bat` (Windows).

You can use it to run Flutter commands! But I recommend you to add the **PATH** variable on your Variable Environment. Then you can run Flutter commands without needs to open its console again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The flutter console is mainly used to run various flutter commands. **$flutter doctor** command is used to check the initial setting which is required to run the flutter application.

[$flutter doctor command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFBDL.png)

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.